# How to use a variable name when creating a json string

Tags: c#

I am doing something like this

```
string tag_prop = "foo_bar";
string guid = "ABC";
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { tags = new { tag_prop = guid } });
```

I noticed that I get the following JSON string.

```
{
tags : {
   tag_prop : "ABC"
        }
}
```

My question is how can I tell the above statement that tag_prop is actually a variable and get this

```
{
    tags : {
       foo_bar: "ABC"
            }
    }
```

Comment: What's the expected output? JSON can't contain variable references.

Comment: just updated my post

Comment: No, you can't use the value of a variable as the name of a property in an anonymous type declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make `tags` a dictionary and use `tag_prop` as the parameter to the indexer.  The following will give you the output you expect (with proper quoting of properties).  If your situation is more complicated, you may have to adapt it futher.

```cs
string tag_prop = "foo_bar";
string guid = "ABC";
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        tags = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            [tag_prop] = guid
        }
    }, Formatting.Indented);
```

The output is:

```
{
  "tags": {
    "foo_bar": "ABC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public static ExpandoObject CreateExpandoObject(string prop, object val)
{
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    expando = AddPropertyWithValue(expando, prop, val is null ? "" : val);
    return expando;
}

public void YourMethod() {
    string tag_prop = "foo_bar";
    string guid = "ABC";
    var dynamicPropertyObject = CreateExpandoObject(tag_prop, guid);
    string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { tags = dynamicPropertyObject });
}
```